# Sending an exception on the SimpleXMLRPCServer

Tags: python, exception, simplexmlrpcserver

I'm trying to raise an exception on the Server Side of an SimpleXMLRPCServer; however, all attempts get a "Fault 1" exception on the client side.

RPC_Server.AbortTest()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1147, in **call**
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1437, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python25\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1201, in request
    return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1340, in _parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 787, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: :Test Aborted by a RPC
request">

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what happens when you raise an exception on the server side. Are you expecting the SimpleXMLRPCServer to return the exception to the client?

You can only use objects that can be marshalled through XML. This includes

- boolean : The True and False constants
- integers : Pass in directly
- floating-point numbers : Pass in directly
- strings : Pass in directly
- arrays : Any Python sequence type containing conformable elements. Arrays are returned as lists
- structures : A Python dictionary. Keys must be strings, values may be any conformable type. Objects of user-defined classes can be passed in; only their `__dict__` attribute is transmitted.
- dates : in seconds since the epoch (pass in an instance of the DateTime class) or a  datetime.datetime instance.
- binary data : pass in an instance of the Binary wrapper class

Answer (score 0):

If you raise an exception like this:

```
raise Exception('Help!')
```

in the server the message member of the exception you get in the client will be the same as executing str() on the original exception prefixed with the string representation of the type.

The result I get for the message member is:

```
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>:Help!
```

You could certainly parse this to get the information you need.